# Deleting the row in php

Tags: php, sql

I have create a database (student) and table(details) in SQL, Fields are Name,Class,Section,Address,Mobile. I need delete the Selva row in that table,I can't delete it please explain!!

PHP code-

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','');
if (!$connection)
{
die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
$select_db = mysql_select_db( "student",$connection);
if (!$select_db)
{
die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
?>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['did'])) {
$delete_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['did']);
$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM details WHERE Name = 'Selva' ");
if($sql) {
    header("Location: table1.php");

} else {
    echo "ERROR";
}
}
?>
```

Please explain ! how to delete the row in a table from database.

Comment: What the _can't delete_ means?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: cannot delete the row!!

Comment: and why do you get an `id` and then delete by "Name='Selva'"?

Comment: Object not found!!!

Comment: Btw. you are using an outdated extension. You should use mysqli instead.

Comment: no i did not given id in the fields

Comment: You have to be more precise what errors (exact wording) you get in which line.

Comment: Are you passing the `did` (eg: index.php?did=1) as query string? then only the delete code will work since you have checking `if(isset($_GET['did'])) {`

Comment: you've been asked 10 mins by @user6838959 as to how you're using that GET array. If you're not going to respond to it and/or update your question with the way you're using it, or if you're even connecting successfully with the present API, then nobody can help you find the solution. You've been given answers below; ask them.

Answer (score -1):

Your mysql query is proper but you need to check below condition is satisfied or not.

```
if(isset($_GET['did'])) {
    echo 'debug test';exit;
}
```